# jQuery Number Counter with Sign

Tags: jquery

How do count up from 0 to number with the sign? Numbers are coming from DB using a custom function to add K, M, B the using jquery counter up to show animation from 0 to lets say 1500, but actual display is 1.5K.

When I run counter() it removes K,M,B and 1.5K become 1.50. I am trying to get exact 1.5K but with counter style animation

```
function number_format_short( $n, $precision = 1 ) {
    if ($n < 900) {
        // 0 - 900
        $n_format = number_format($n, $precision);
        $suffix = '';
    } else if ($n < 900000) {
        // 0.9k-850k
        $n_format = number_format($n / 1000, $precision);
        $suffix = 'K';
    } else if ($n < 900000000) {
        // 0.9m-850m
        $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000, $precision);
        $suffix = 'M';
    } else if ($n < 900000000000) {
        // 0.9b-850b
        $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000000, $precision);
        $suffix = 'B';
    } else {
        // 0.9t+
        $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000000000, $precision);
        $suffix = 'T';
    }
  // Remove unecessary zeroes after decimal. "1.0" -> "1"; "1.00" -> "1"
  // Intentionally does not affect partials, eg "1.50" -> "1.50"
    if ( $precision > 0 ) {
        $dotzero = '.' . str_repeat( '0', $precision );
        $n_format = str_replace( $dotzero, '', $n_format );
    }
    return $n_format . $suffix;
}

function counter(){
    $('.cnts').each(function (index) {
        var size = $(this).text().split(".")[1] ? $(this).text().split(".")[1].length : 0;
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 1500,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(parseFloat(now).toFixed(size));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: And `php` here does what?

Comment: add K,M,B to number and round it up.

Comment: Can't replicate your problem. https://3v4l.org/fOaQK

Comment: did you stored data in 1k(short number format) in database? Please store actual data instead of shorten them @Zack

Comment: in DB is eg 1496, which rounds up to 1500 and display as 1.5K

Comment: i think the problem is on this part. `$(this).text(parseFloat(now).toFixed(size));` -- var `size` is of string after `.`

Comment: `1.5K` is a string. Using `toFixed` shouldn't work on strings and doing `parseFloat` will remove the `K` in the end making all the PHP code useless. This question is really unclear as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can so something like:

Remove the suffix letter (K,M,B etc) first and store on a variable. And append it when you update the text.

```js
$('.cnts').each(function(index) {
  var letter = $(this).text().match(/\D$/)[0]; /* Store the letter on variable */
  var text =  $(this).text().replace(/\D$/,""); /* Remove the letter from string so that you can calculate the number of decimal correctly */ 
  var size = text.split(".")[1] ? text.split(".")[1].length : 0;

  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: text
  }, {
    duration: 1500,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(parseFloat(now).toFixed(size) + letter); /* Append the letter here. */
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cnts">1.5K</div>
```

Comment: Instead of a slice you should do a regex match and replace of `/\D$/` to not trim the last digit of an unsuffixed value.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for the suggestion. Updated :)